# Authenticating Soap with "Global Http Settings"

Tags: .net, authentication, soap, wsdl, http-headers

I have to connect to a SOAP service from C#.NET, but the service only accepts requests with http authentication headers.

It seems (based on my googleing so far) like authentication via Http headers is not standard for SOAP, but I cannot make any changes to the SOAP service.

Note: I am not talking about SOAP headers.

I can set up the http authentication and make successful requests with SoapUI as shown:

[image: Working SoapUI request, using "Username" and "Password" in the Authorisation tab]

I may be wrong about what SoapUI is doing behind the scenes - this is http authentication right?

I have imported the WSDL to my Visual Studio project, and can attempt to make requests but I get a "401 - Unauthorised (The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. )" error of course.

I'd like to invoke the service in a way something like this:

```
    public List<string> GetVinsForUser(string customerId)
    {
        var client = new CustomerService.VehicleClient();

        // client.HttpHeaders.Add("username", "SomeUser");
        // client.HttpHeaders.Add("password", "SomePassword");

        var result = client.findCustomerPlusVehicles(customerId);

        return result.Vehicles.ToList();
    }
```

All the related articles I've seen so far seem to imply there is no easy property like this for the .NET implementation of SOAP.

I understand I could POST soap xml data to the endpoint building the entire webrequest by hand, but I really really don't want to hack this!

Are there any ways to enable this kind of authentication, even by extending / overriding the behaviour of the generated Client class?

Comment: look at the raw tab you'll see how soapUI is sending its request. I think it add the authentication information to the payload.

Comment: yes in the raw tab I see "Authorization: Basic Y2Ntd........."
My issue is how do you add http basic authentication to SOAP requests in the default .NET SOAP client.

Comment: i don't know what exactly is the problem but if its a web service it should have an Endpoint and also if the authentication is Basic HTTP then why u don't try to change the Endpoint Address To [https://Username:Password@serviceHost.com:portXX/demoService](https://Username:Password@serviceHost.com:portXX/demoService)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify the soap headers directly, just let .net modify the headers:

```
// windows credential
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("yourUsername", "yourPassword", "yourDomain.com");

// you can also try this
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "yourUsername";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "yourPassword";
```